# CakePHP3.4: Why Request::getHeader() returns an array?

Tags: cakephp, http-headers, httpresponse, cakephp-3.4

I have the following request:

```
2017-04-05 06:53:31 Error: Cake\Http\ServerRequest Object
(
    ...
    [_environment:protected] => Array
        (
            [HTTP_REGISTRATION] => eur73_9lhfQ:...SJMryPxCNzKcqSufdpFMOaux
            ...
        )

    [_detectorCache:protected] => Array
        (
            [ajax] => 
            [get] => 1
            [head] => 
            [options] => 
            [post] => 
        )

    [uri:protected] => Zend\Diactoros\Uri Object
        (
            [allowedSchemes:protected] => Array
                (
                    [http] => 80
                    [https] => 443
                )
            ...

        )
    ...
)
```

`$this->request->header['registration']` returns:

```
eur73_9lhfQ:...SJMryPxCNzKcqSufdpFMOaux
```

as string

$this->request->getHeader('registration') returns:

```
[Registration] => Array
    (
        [0] => eur73_9lhfQ:...SJMryPxCNzKcqSufdpFMOaux
    )
```

Why does it return an array?

Comment: because it is implemented to return an array -)) https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Http/ServerRequest.php#L1029

Comment: @marmeladze lol. To just return a single element !?!

Comment: sometimes it is hard to understand the developers' intentions&motivations. ask someone from team on github -))

Comment: @marmeladze, yes looks funny, but there is certainly a reason....

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP standard allows multiple headers with the same field name to be present in case all values of that header can be expressed as a single, comma separated string (`Set-Cookie` is an exception to that rule, it cannot express multiple values in a single string, but in practice does still appear multiple times in order to define multiple cookies).

In order to support this in a convenient way, the PSR-7 standard (which `\Cake\Http\ServerRequest` complies to) defines the `getHeader()` method to return header values as arrays. The complement to that is the `getHeaderLine()` method, which is ment to return multiple values as a single, comma separated string.

See also

- **https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.2**
- **http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/#headers-with-multiple-values**